# Bullet physics with Visual Studio 2013

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, bullet

So, I'm trying to use bullet physics in Visual studio 2013. I downloaded version 2.83, builded it with VS and cmake, and added bullet projects to dependencies. It is working, and i can use bullet stuff (I include btBulletDynamicsCommon.h and btBulletCollisionCommon.h), but if I try to for example use btVector3 as an parameter, I get the following error:

```
Error   1   error C2719: 'v': formal parameter with __declspec(align('16')) won't be aligned
```

Answer (score 0):

This is caused by BulletPhysics writing code that's not strictly compatible with Win32.

You can fix it like I did by changing offending functions to take a const Reference instead of by value. Alternatively you can write a 64-bit only app.